# Whatever: pronoun, conjunction or determiner?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, determiners

I have already learned what is the general difference between conjunctions and conjuncting pronouns, and that is the fact that a pronoun can be a subject or an object in the clause whereas a conjunction can not. But it seems, there are still exceptions like "whoever" and "whatever".

So, in the sentence below "whatever" is certainly a pronoun. Here, the dependent clause is a noun clause.

> You are free to do whatever you want.

But in the next sentence, which contains adverbial clause, "whatever" seems to be a conjunction (because like any subordinating conjunction, it shows the relationship between clauses).

> I won`t leave her whatever happens.

This I more or less understood although I can`t quite get why Macmillan dictionary says that "whatever "can be both pronoun and conjunction while Lexico (Oxford) says that it can only be a pronoun...

But the real trouble is from now on!
In the sentence

> Whatever decision he made I would support it.

"whatever" seems to function like a conjunction, but it`s placed before the noun just like a determiner. So, what is it here: determiner or conjunction? Or maybe even pronoun?

I don`t get it! Please, help me.

Comment: [correction: I have already learned what general difference is between etc.]

Comment: whatever decision = regardless of the decision, adjective, for sure.

Comment: "Whatever" belongs solely to the **determinative** category, either interrogative ("Whatever present you buy for him, he won't be satisfied") or relative ("We'll use whatever edition is available").

Comment: @BillJ You forget that there are two verbs in this sentence, and therefore two clauses that you have to fit, somehow, into the usual order of things as pertains to grammar.

Comment: @LPH: No: "Whatever present you buy for him" is not a sentence but an interrogative clause functioning as an adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ I am talking about the OP's sentence, of course (Whatever decision he made I would support it.).

Comment: @LPH. It's the same kind of construction. "Whatever decision he made" is an interrogative clause functioning as an adjunct in an exhaustive conditional. You need to study this kind of construction.

Comment: @BillJ How do you connect it to the other clause?

Comment: @LPH. There is no internal marker of subordination: it is shown to be subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction.

Comment: @BillJ Sorry, I can't go on: I have been suspended on another site, with the consequence of not being allowed to use chat sections whatever the site I am in; as my comment here is already one too many I must stop.

Comment: @BillJ Let me get it right. So, you say that in the sentences like "Whatever decision he made I would support it" "whatever" is always a determinative, right? Or do you imply that it`s really ALWAYS a determinative, even in "You are free to do whatever you want"?

Comment: Yes to both your questions.

Comment: @BillJ Ok, thanks for your answer. Could you also tell me what grammar book you are sticking to, please?

Comment: I use the award-winning _Cambridge Grammar of The English Language_ by Huddleston & Pullum as a reference grammar. See here:[link](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language?format=HB)

Comment: @BillJ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Whatever decision he made I would support it.

The parsing of this sentence corresponds well to a case analysed in CoGEL, except for a small difference which amounts to the use of an article. That is, the analysis would be perfectly right if the sentence were written as follows.

- Whatever *the* decision he made I would support it.

Therefore, I'll still provide this explanation, as it is closely connected.

In this sentence "Whatever the decision he made"  is termed *universal conditional-concessive clause* and "whatever" is a subordinator (CoGEL **14.20** p. 1006). It is called universal because the wh-word implies a totality; the other type (alternative conditional-concessive) is introduced by "*whether … or*" or "*or*". The reason for combining "conditional" with "concessive" is that it is found that in this context there is overlap between the two ideas. (CoGEL **15.41**, pp. 1099-1100)

It is a little tricky as a verb is omitted. The sentence without ellipsis, which is usable too, could read as follows.

- Whatever would be the decision (that) he made I would support it.

The concessive implication comes through inferences such as "*even* if a decision had been less than good I would have supported it".

> (CoGEL **15.42**, pp. 1001-1002)
> Note The verb *"be*" can be omitted from a universal clause if the subject of an SVC clause is an abstract noun phrase:
> *Whatever your problems (are/may be),* they can't be worse than mine.

Comment: "Whatever" is **never** a subordinator. That's simply nonsense.

Comment: @BillJ I/ Michael Swan, _Practical English Usage_, OUP 1996, p.595 n° 596 § 1 (meaning and use): "_A word of this kind has a double function, like a relative pronoun or adverb (see 473): it acts as a subject, object or adverb in its own clause, but it also acts as a conjunction, joining its clause to the rest of the sentence. II/ A clause such as "whatever happens" can't stand on its own; therefore it is a **dependent clause** in the sentence where it is found. Only "whatever" can be a marker of that dependence; it is therefore a subordinator.

Comment: Ignore Swan -- he is wrong. "Whatever" is always a **determinative**. English has only 5 subordinators: "that", "for", "to", "whether", and "if".

Comment: @BillJ Ignore Swan is easier said than done: what's your parsing of these two clauses? You'll never get away with two independent clauses. What's left?

Comment: @BillJ There is, however, one possibility, albeit somewhat far-fetched: you can suppose an _extreme case_ ellipsis of "and this is so". In this case you can speak of two coordinated independent clauses, but can we go as far as that? I don't know at all, this means allowing multiple interpretations in all sorts of situations, havoc in perspective. (1/2)

Comment: @BillJ Nevertheless, the problem recurs in  "This is so whatever happens.". (2/2)

Comment: "This is so, whatever happens" is an exhaustive conditional construction, where "whatever" is a determinative. It's always a determinative, either interrogative ("Whatever present you buy for him, he won't be satisfied") or relative ("We'll use whatever edition is available").

Comment: @BillJ  Sorry, I can't go on: I have been suspended on another site, with the consequence of not being allowed to use chat sections whatever the site I am in; as my comment here is already one too many I must stop.

Comment: @LPH Thank you for your answer. By the way, what is CoGEL? Is it "The Cambridge Grammar..."?

Comment: @Moongrel No, this is the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, by Quirk et al, of which there is a more recent edition than the one I am referring to. I use "CoGEL" because usually when people mention the CGEL they mean the Cambridge Grammar.

Comment: @LPH Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Pronoun**: 1880   M. Oliphant He that will Not xxiii   *Whatever can you want to emigrate for?*

**Pronoun**: As nominal relative, in a generalized or indefinite sense: 1883   D. C. Murray Hearts i   *We'll lay in whatever you want to-morrow.*

**Adverb**: 1980   New Musical Express 12 Jan. 33/1   *Whatever, the myth looks momentous in its sleek new American threads.*

**Noun**: 2001   Jerusalem Post (Electronic ed.) 23 Feb. 7   *I drove down there..and bought..this stuff. It contains seven different whatevers. On the package it said ‘Good for peace in the home against evil eye and all kinds of disturbances and fear’.*

**Adjective**: 1884   Marshall's Tennis Cuts 94   *That a player using a racket had no chance whatever against an opponent catching and throwing the ball.*

**Determiner**: 1906   H. Belloc Hills & Sea 176   *In whatever place a man may be the spring will come to him.*

Comment: Yet, not a conjunction in sight.

Comment: Lexico acknowledges an adverb and not an adjective in case 4 but an adverb: https://www.lexico.com/definition/whatever. In fact, as far as lexico is concerned this word can't be an adjective. It is not an adjective in CoGEL.

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble, but "whatever" belongs solely to the determinative category, either interrogative, e.g. "Whatever present you buy for him, he won't be satisfied", or relative, e.g. "We'll use whatever edition is available".

Comment: @BillJ - Yeah... whatever...